# Android App (Webview) crashes because of splashscreen

Tags: java, android, xml, webview

Some phones (e.g. Samsung S6 or S7) cannot start my android webview app. This is what I got from the google play store:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:

  at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw (DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
  at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap (Canvas.java:1420)
  at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw (BitmapDrawable.java:545)
  at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw (ImageView.java:1286)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18318)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17296)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18080)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17291)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18080)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17291)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18080)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17291)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18080)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17291)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18080)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17291)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18080)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18321)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw (DecorView.java:919)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17296)
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList (ThreadedRenderer.java:692)
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList (ThreadedRenderer.java:698)
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw (ThreadedRenderer.java:806)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw (ViewRootImpl.java:3128)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw (ViewRootImpl.java:2924)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2516)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1515)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:7091)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:927)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:702)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:638)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:913)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6682)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

It seems to be my splashscreen, this is it:

activity_main.xml:

```
//splashscreen fullscreen
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/splash1"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:src="@drawable/redsplashscreen"
    />

//shows the webview fullscreen
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
```

MainActivity.java snippet:

```
boolean splashFinished = false;

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        //loads splashscreen once till website is loaded
        if (!splashFinished) {
            //hides loading image
            findViewById(R.id.splash1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //shows webview
            findViewById(R.id.web1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            splashFinished = true;
        }
```

Some people here said that I have to move the image from "drawable"-folder to "drawable-xxhd", and I tried it, but when I want to create a APK, android studio moves it back and changes the code of xml.

BTW the image is not really big, I changed the size from 1.7MB to 0.7MB.

Comment: Could you show detail code ?

Comment: what do you want to see more?

Comment: Detail Logcat and more code about MainActivity .

Comment: Reduce the size of the splash screen. Issue stems from drawing the image.

Comment: i reduced it to 0.7 mb. is that still to big?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, some phone cannot handle big splash image file.
Mine was 1.xMB and after I reduce file size, no more crash.

Reduce file size.

Comment: the image is smaller than 1MB.

Comment: Try with other image. very small.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution: inside android studio I made "drawable-xxhdpi"-folder (right-click "res" -> new -> directory). And I put the same splashscreen image inside this folder. This way, it doesn't change anything of the aactivity_main.xml.